# Is there a Console on Windows for process analyses?

Tags: windows, console

In Mac OS X there is a program called Console which shows a log of what operations the OS has been doing. This makes it easy to pinpoint errors for me is there an equal application on the windows distributions or as a download for the Windows OS?

Here how the console looks like in OS X:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event Viewer might help. Search for Event Viewer using the start menu in Windows 7 or Vista, or run "eventvwr.msc" from the run box or command prompt.

Comment: Actually eventviewer does the Job described but somehow it's very hard for me to pinpoint failures as the GUI is very bloated and searching for errors is pain in the a**

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's free Process Explorer from the SysInternals suite may be what you are looking for:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx